# What calls the setters in an Entity?

Tags: entity-framework

In Entity Framework, you must create a class that derives from `DbContext` with IDbSet properties.  What in Entity Framework calls the setters and how does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your custom context class is instantiated, the base `DbContext` constructor calls a private method called `InitializeLazyInternalContext` which in turn calls another private method called `DiscoverAndInitializeSets`.

This method creates a new instance of a `DbSetDiscoveryService`, passing in the current context as a constructor parameter, and then calls its `InitializeSets` method. This method in turn calls `GetSets` which uses reflection to get a list of any property on the derived context that is assignable from `DbSet<T>` (this includes `IDbSet<T>`).

It then loops through this collection and providing the property isn't marked with a `SuppressDbSetInitializationAttribute`, it assigns an instance of a `DbSet<T>` by invoking the DbContext's `Set<TEntity>` method and assigning the result.

You can view the `DbSetDiscoveryService` code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/main/src/EntityFramework/Internal/DbSetDiscoveryService.cs).

Answer (score 0):

EF uses reflection to discover IDbSet properties on DbContext derived classes and sets them accordingly.