# Storing DbSet in constructor instead of calling DbContext.Set<TU> for every use

Tags: entity-framework, repository, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, dbset

In a repository pattern I've been following for a while ([example](https://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/)), I've always had Add, Delete, etc. methods which use a "new" DbSet (e.g., `DbContext.Set<T>.Update(entity)`. In testing, this seems to, thankfully, always return the same DbSet object. Is there any reason I should not call `DbContext.Set<T>()` once in the constructor and save it as a property instead of calling `Set<T>()` in every method? I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

This snippet was taken from the same link:
[image: From the article linked earlier]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason I should not call DbContext.Set() once in the constructor and save it as a property instead of calling Set() in every method?

No.  That's exactly what a normal DbContext does on initialization.  See [What calls the setters in an Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734246/what-calls-the-setters-in-an-entity)